# download images from url to viewpager

Tags: android, image, url, android-viewpager

i have group of  of images url in array of string ,now i want to display them in view pager , i tried to display images from  folders and it's worked .but when i used array of  string ,the images don't show  . so what's the problem? that is part of my code.

```
 ViewPager viewPager;
CustomerAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    String [] urls={"https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/styles/image_card_4x3_ratio/public/thumbnails/image/pia20645_main.jpg?itok=dLn7SngD","http://www.gettyimages.pt/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/PT/PT_hero_42_153645159.jpg","http://humminglove.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/l-is-l.jpg"};

    viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    adapter = new CustomerAdapter(this,urls);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);


}
```

that is adapter

```
public class CustomerAdapter extends PagerAdapter{
private int[] images = {R.mipmap.img1,R.mipmap.img2,R.mipmap.img3,R.mipmap.img4};
private Context ctx;
private  String[] urls;
private LayoutInflater inflater;

public CustomerAdapter(Context ctx,String []urls){
    this.ctx = ctx;
    this.urls=urls;
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return urls.length;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return (view ==(LinearLayout)object);
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    inflater =  (LayoutInflater)ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.swip,container,false);
    ImageView img =(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.imagee);
    TextView tv  = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    Picasso.with(ctx).load(urls[position]).into(img);
    tv.setText("Image :"+position);
    container.addView(v);
    return v;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(View container, int position, Object object) {
    container.refreshDrawableState();
}
```

}

that's my main_activity xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="web.blu_ray91111.example.commyc.newwww.MainActivity">


<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id ="@+id/view_pager"
    android:layout_height="300dp"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"

    >
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

swip.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:text="Hello world!"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:gravity="center" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imagee"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case it is not clear why it didn't loaded.
1) It might take time to load big images
2) Some network error occurred on loading images

So I am you to use placeholders to coverup the error and on loading time of images.

```
Picasso.with(mContext).load(fileImage)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder_img)
                .error(R.drawable.error_placeholder_img).into(img)
```

> Check you can access the url by normal browser

Comment: first:i tried to download small image ("http://stat.homeshop18.com/homeshop18/images/productImages/534/soft-toys-small-size-mm-1610-medium_56966da6d713dc84e2679c19a01b67dc.jpg").still no images show.                                                                                                          second :i used place holder ,the image  in it show but not image of url .  also i am sure of internet connection i download image to imageview outside the view pager and the image shows.

Comment: is it accessible via browser, I tried to open it, It is not opening.

Comment: http://stat.homeshop18.com/homeshop18/images/productImages/534/soft-toys-small-size-mm-1610-medium_56966da6d713dc84e2679c19a01b67dc.jpg

Comment: i checked it , it opens image

Comment: I am not sure, Can you share the project if it opensource and not a secret one?? So that I can check

Comment: in ".into(img)" add second param as callback, ".into(img, callback)" and log the implemented method and tell me the result.

Comment: i tried it on my phone and it  worked maybe the probleme in emulator